General Formula For Hadamard Gate on Superposition State
The general formula for Hadamard Gate $H$, is $$H|x\rangle = \Sigma_z(-1)^{xz}|z\rangle/\sqrt{2}\tag{1}\label{1}$$ for n gates in parallel $$H^{\otimes n}|x\rangle = \Sigma_z(-1)^{x.z}|z\rangle/\sqrt{2^n}\tag{2}\label{2}$$ my question is that are these formulas true even if $|x\rangle$ is a superposition state say $\alpha |0\rangle  +\beta|1\rangle$? For states $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ it is easy to see that it works. I was unable to prove or determine if the formula works for superposition states because I dont know what will be $x.z$ in that case, cause x is not merely 0 or 1. $\eqref{2}$ is used in the proof of Deutsch-Jozsa Algorithm(in the book by Nielsen and Chuang) in the final step when Hadamard Gate is applied on the data register, hence $\eqref{2}$ and $\eqref{1}$ must be correct for superposition sates $|x\rangle$ as well.

From the math point of view, there's an exact answer to your question.
Suppose $|\psi\rangle = \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n} f(x) |x\rangle$.  Then
$$H^{\otimes n}|\psi\rangle = \sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n} \hat f(y) |y\rangle,$$
where $\hat f$ is the $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$-Fourier transform of $f$, i.e., (complicated way resembling $\prod_j\mathbb{Z}_{m_j}$-FT)
$$\hat f(y) = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n} e^{-2\pi i (\sum_j y_j x_j/2)} \, f(x)$$
which simplifies to (easy way)
$$\dots = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{y^\top x} f(x).$$
While on the surface that's writing something obvious and using a fancy name, the fact of the matter is that FT of Boolean functions has properties that can be used to reason with ease about quantum algorithms such as Deutsch-Josza, Bernstein-Vazirani, Simon's, ...

I was just reading about that from this link, paragraph 4.
That expression of a "Tensorial" Hadamard gate applies for $ |x\rangle $ as a generic n state, $ x = x_{1}x_{2}..x_n \in \{0,1\}^{n} $
Every item in x is either 0 or 1.

The para in the link states about the case $x_i \in {0,1}$ which I am convinced is true, but my question is about the case when $x_i$ is in superposition state. Does the same formula apply? If so then what is $x.z$ in this case? Also the general formula is used even for superposition state $x_i$ in Nielsen and Chuang book in the proof of Deutsch-Jozsa Algorithm.

Ok, I understand what you mean. Let me show it. Let say you have a value of x such as $ x= x_{1}x_{2}..x_c..x_n $, with $x_1..x_{c-1}\in \{0,1\}^{c-1}$, $x_{c+1}..x_{n}\in \{0,1\}^{n-c}$ and $x_c = \alpha |0\rangle  + \beta|1 \rangle $. It is important to take into consideration $ x= x_{1}x_{2}..x_c..x_n $ is the equivalent to $ x= x_{1}\otimes x_{2}..x_c\otimes..\otimes x_n $, so a tensor product. You could express,$ x = x_1x_2..(\alpha |0\rangle  + \beta|1 \rangle)..x_n = x_1x_2..\alpha |0\rangle..x_n + x_1x_2..\beta|1 \rangle ..x_n $ and could get $\alpha$ and $\beta$ out, so that $x = x_1x_2..\alpha |0\rangle..x_n + x_1x_2..\beta|1 \rangle ..x_n = \alpha (x_1x_2.. |0\rangle..x_n) + \beta ( x_1x_2..|1 \rangle ..x_n)  $.  And then if you apply $ H^{\otimes n}|x\rangle = \alpha H^{\otimes n}|x_1x_2.. 0..x_n\rangle + \beta H^{\otimes n}|x_1x_2..1..x_n\rangle$, where you can apply the general formulae.
